# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars - complex numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, math

I have tried to plot a graph with complex values using Python 2.7. But the code did not return the complex values for the y values.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cmath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
     return ((x)*cmath.sqrt((x)+0.5)*((x)+1))


x=np.linspace(-4,-2,10)
y=f(x)
plt.plot( x,y, label=fx_name)
plt.title('sample ')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The error is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Happy/Demo/code10.py", line 12, in <module>
    y=f(x)
  File "/home/Happy/Demo/code10.py", line 7, in f
    return ((x)*cmath.sqrt((x)+0.5)*((x)+1))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Try replacing `cmath.sqrt` with `np.sqrt`. And you need to cast `x` to `complex` type, i.e. `x.astype(complex)`.

Comment: you seem to be tring to find the square roots of negative numbers.

Comment: yes. That's why the output produces errors

Comment: `x = x.astype(np.complex128); return x*np.sqrt(x+0.5)*(x+1)`

Comment: The problem is that `cmath` like `math` only works with scalar values.  Your `x` is an array, 10 values, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

try it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x):
    return ((x) * np.sqrt((x) + 0.5) * ((x) + 1))


x = np.linspace(-4, -2, 10).astype(np.complex)
y = f(x)

plt.plot(y.real, y.imag,'*')
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    plt.text(y.real[i], y.imag[i],"x="+str(x.real[i]))
plt.title('sample')
plt.xlabel('y real')
plt.ylabel('y imag')
plt.show()
```